# Open chrome url with extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a custom start page for the new tab page for google chrome. In my HTML I have a link to `chrome://apps`, however when I click on it I get the error:

`Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://apps/`

Here is my manifest

```
    "name": "<name>",
    "description": "<description>",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
      "chrome_url_overrides" : {
        "newtab": "newtab.html"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
      ],
      "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": {
      "script-src": "self",
       "object-src": "self"
      },
      "optional_permissions": ["bookmarks", "topSites"]
  }
```

and this is the html file :

```
newtab.html ...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My new tab page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="chrome://apps/">Apps</a>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a click handler and use chrome.tabs.create inside with this url.

Comment: @wOxxOm well it works, but I have seen extensions that can do it natively

Comment: This is the native method.

Comment: @wOxxOm I checked the source of this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=en and they don't use the method you suggested, it works just with the href, so there is a proper way to do it

Comment: If you debug it all the way through, you'll see it uses the same method, https://puu.sh/IhLcN/0b9dc5cc72.png, choosing `create` or `update` depending on preference. There are no other methods.

Comment: @wOxxOm alright thank you! I also added event.preventDefault() to omit the error message from the console.